# Is there any existed open source project for messaging infrastructure?

Tags: java, open-source, messaging, infrastructure

I want to know if there is any open source projects for messaging infrastructure. It will cover most functionalities listed in "Enterprise Integration Patterns". I know there are some open source ESB products which are following this book. But it seems they are too heavy. I only want an elegant messaging infrastructure.

Comment: It will cover most fuctionalities listed in . ??? There is some content missing here.

Comment: Maybe you should list the functionalities you're looking for. There are lot of messaging middleware or ESB products otherwise.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I don't want an ESB, I only want a simple messaging middleware wich can cover most functionalities in the book <enterprise integration patterns> written by Gregor Hohpe, Bobby Woolf

Comment: Not everyone has read the book, maybe list some required functionality?

Comment: "heavy" here means: The functionalities it provides are fay beyond what I need.

Comment: I want to make some clarification: What I am seeking is NOT a MOM or ESB. Since I am developing a trading system which is an message-driven architecture, I need some messaging tools to cooperate with MOM to act as my messaging infrastructure. There is a home-grown framework in our firm, but there is some performance issue with it. In my opinion, it at least includes the following functionalities: 1) producer/consumer utility class with configurable properties (group, selector) 2) support topic hierarchy (wildcard) 3) transaction support 4) resequencer 5)

Comment: transaction management 6) message exception management 7) chained message filter (configurable) 8) Condition-based dynamic router 9) Aggregator. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/)? It implements some of Enterprise Integration Patterns.

Comment: Will have a look at Camel, many thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

How about [Mule](http://www.mulesoft.org/)?

Comment: Yeah, it all depends on exactly "how enterprise" you want to be. I agree that just plain old JMS is very useful; same way as a servlet container covers most of things one wants instead of full EJB container.

Comment: Which requirements lead Mule to be too heavy? Mule's download includes a lot of libraries since it supports a wide range of protocols out of the box. However, it is easy when building your project with Maven to only include the dependencies you really need, resulting in a much smaller package.

From a runtime resource perspective Mule is very lightweight. It have almost no overhead and can be run standalone or embedded in your app server or java applications. 

You may want to look at the new patterns and flow support in Mule 3. It gives you even easier ways do things.

http://bit.ly/aeu8he

Comment: Sure, will definitely have a look at Mule 3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what qualifies for an Enterprise messaging infrastructure, but has [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) been investigated?

Comment: +1, and the openfire server looks very promising in Java

Comment: I don't know XMPP before. It seems XMPP is designated for general purpose, I want a product in JMS world. Could you please help to share some experiences?

Comment: The Google wave federation prototype uses (used?) Openfire, which is written in Java. You mentioned only needing an elegant messaging infrastructure, which XMPP/Openfire certainly is.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but it seems XMPP or Openfire are mostly used for IM. I want to a product limited to Java/JMS

Comment: There are lots of JMS implementations; ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, Swift to name some.